# Python calculation including e

Tags: python

[image]

```
print(0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5+1e+16): 1.0000000000000002e+16


print(1e+16+0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5): 1e+16
```

Why these two answers differ?

Comment: 0.5 is too small to add to `1e16`; but 2 (`0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5`) is just big enough to be added to `1e16`.

Comment: Because the expressions are evaluated one by one from left to right. 
In the first case, you get 2 + 1e+16 which is enough to make a difference in floating point system. But in the second case, each time you add 0.5 it's not enough to change the representation (there is a limit in precision of floats), the result is always "rounded down" to 1e+16 each time.

Comment: Thank you so much, I’ve just started learning and this is so helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

It is because how Python parses the expressions.

Let's use the `ast` module to see:

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: print(ast.dump(ast.parse("0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5+1e+16"), indent=4))
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=BinOp(
                left=BinOp(
                    left=BinOp(
                        left=BinOp(
                            left=Constant(value=0.5),
                            op=Add(),
                            right=Constant(value=0.5)),
                        op=Add(),
                        right=Constant(value=0.5)),
                    op=Add(),
                    right=Constant(value=0.5)),
                op=Add(),
                right=Constant(value=1e+16)))],
    type_ignores=[])
```

The code above basically first adds all the `0.5` values (yielding `2.0`) and then adds that to `1e16`.

```
In [6]: 1e16+2
Out[6]: 1.0000000000000002e+16
```

```
In [3]: print(ast.dump(ast.parse("1e+16+0.5+0.5+0.5+0.5"), indent=4))
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=BinOp(
                left=BinOp(
                    left=BinOp(
                        left=BinOp(
                            left=Constant(value=1e+16),
                            op=Add(),
                            right=Constant(value=0.5)),
                        op=Add(),
                        right=Constant(value=0.5)),
                    op=Add(),
                    right=Constant(value=0.5)),
                op=Add(),
                right=Constant(value=0.5)))],
    type_ignores=[])
```

The other code adds `0.5` to `1e16` four times.
*However, this doesn't work because `0.5` is too small to change `1e16`*:

```
In [7]: 1e16+0.5 == 1e16
Out[7]: True
```

This basically has to do with the nature of floating point numbers. Look at `sys.float_info.dig`; this will tell you how many digits the `float` type can handle on your machine:

```
In [23]: import sys

In [24]: sys.float_info.dig
Out[24]: 15
```

In a case like this, consider using `decimal.Decimal` numbers:

```
In [21]: from decimal import Decimal

In [22]: Decimal("1e16")+Decimal("0.5")+Decimal("0.5")+Decimal("0.5")+Decimal("0.5")
Out[22]: Decimal('10000000000000002.0')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer, will do my best to learn!